# Rails - Can't run rails server because of spring gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I could run the rails project yesterday on local.

But today I can't run the project with the below issues.

I haven't done anything.
I am using **Spring 2.1.0**

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/work/halfhelix/floravere/heroku_floravere_dev/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I know this issue is a commonly known issue.

I have researched to fix issues but I couldn't fix it.

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: if you perform what it suggests? bundle exec spring binstub --all

Comment: try `bin/spring stop`.

Comment: @Fernand, it didn't help me.

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay, it didn't hep me.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666916/6270554 ?

Comment: what is the result of this command: gem list spring

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay, tried but id didn't help me.

Comment: @Fernand, *** LOCAL GEMS ***

spring (2.1.0)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)

Answer (score -1):

There was a code issue.
I wrote the details how I fixed it.

[The way to fix this issue](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/610)